# ElasticSearch 2.0 NEST migration

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-2.0

I have used elastic 1.7 before. After migration to 2.0 I have faced with several issues (here are those I am most focus currently): *mapping attributes*, *json serialization*.

I have used next attributes I can't find in 2.0 version -  `ElasticProperty`with property `Name, Boost, OptOut` .

I can't find replacement for `settitgs.SetJsonSerializerSettingsModifier(x => x.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset)` in new api.

The only useful document I found is [breaking changes](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/docs/2.0-breaking-changes/nest-breaking-changes.md). Sadly, but [nest examples](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/) are outdated. Possible I have missed something easy, please point me in right direction.

**Edit**

So,  `Name, Boost` are part of `String` attribute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ad1.

This part has been refactored and right now you can't use `ElasticProperty`. It has been replaced with bunch of new attributes(as described in [breaking changes notes](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/docs/2.0-breaking-changes/nest-breaking-changes.md#attribute-based-mapping))

For example

```
[ElasticProperty(Name="name", Boost = 1.1, OptOut = true)]
public string Name {get; set;}
```

it's equivalent to

```
[String(Name="name", Boost = 1.1, Ignore = true)]
public string Name {get; set;}
```

etc.

Ad2.

You can modify your serialization settings by passing custom `JsonNetSerializer` to `ConnectionSettings`, just like this:

```
var connectionPool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool, connectionSettings => new MyJsonNetSerializer(connectionSettings))
    .DefaultIndex(indexName)
    .DisableDirectStreaming()
    .PrettyJson();

public class MyJsonNetSerializer : JsonNetSerializer
{
    public MyJsonNetSerializer(IConnectionSettingsValues settings) : base(settings)
    {
    }

    protected override void ModifyJsonSerializerSettings(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings)
    {
        settings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset;
    }
}
```

More details [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/pull/1703) and [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1849).

I hope it's gonna make your migration easier :)

Comment: QueryDescriptor<T> is not available in NEST 2.x, @Rob , Can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38136094/what-is-the-alternative-to-querydescriptor-nest-2-x