# How to convert attributes in NEST 2

Tags: upgrade, nest

I am trying to upgrade from NEST 1.7.1 to 2.0.4, and I am having a REALLY hard time figuring out how to fix all the attribute errors. I simply cannot find any adequate documentation. The one available at http://nest.azurewebsites.net/ is not up to date.

I'm specifically having issues converting `[ElasticProperty(OptOut = true)]` and `[ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]`.

For simple strings I can do something like `[String(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]`, but it doesn't seem like I can do the same for numeric types, and I cannot figure out how to `OptOut`.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502725/elasticsearch-2-0-nest-migration/35503235#35503235) answer should help you with your problem. For numeric types mapping check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502725/elasticsearch-2-0-nest-migration/35503235#35503235) one. Hope it helps.

Comment: I managed to get by, reading https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/docs/2.0-breaking-changes/nest-breaking-changes.md#attribute-based-mapping and http://blog.huilaaja.net/2016/03/15/elasticsearch-nest-2-upgrade-version/. Your comment lead me onto it, so thanks :)